# CD/DVD burn error in ImgBurn and Nero

Tags: dvd, burning, optical-drive, compact-disc, imgburn

I am getting the errors shown below when I try to burn a CD/DVD on my DVD writer. I am seeing this error for every CD/DVD I try to burn. I am not able to write any CDs or DVDs using ImgBurn. The burn log below is a failed burn in Nero.

What could be causing this error?

[image: screenshot]

```
Nero Burning ROM bobby 4C85-200E-4005-0004-0000-7660-0800-35X3-0000-407M-MX37-**** (*) 
Windows XP 6.1 IA32 
WinAspi: - NT-SPTI used 
Nero Version: 7.11.3. 
Internal Version: 7, 11, 3,  (Nero Express) 
Recorder:             <HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-H12N>
Version: UL01 - HA 1 TA 1 - 7.11.3.0  
Adapter driver:      <IDE>                     HA 1  
Drive buffer  :      2048kB  
Bus Type      :      
default CD-ROM:               <ATAPI-CD ROM-DRIVE-52MAX >
Version: 52PP - HA 1 TA 0 - 7.11.3.0  
Adapter driver:      <IDE>                     HA 1

=== Scsi-Device-Map === === CDRom-Device-Map ===
ATAPI-CD ROM-DRIVE-52MAX   F:   
CdRom0 HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-H12N   G:   
CdRom1 
=======================
AutoRun : 1 Excluded drive 
IDs: 
WriteBufferSize: 83886080 (0) Byte BUFE           : 0 
Physical memory     : 958MB (981560kB) 
Free physical memory: 309MB (317024kB) 
Memory in use       : 67 % 
Uncached PFiles: 0x0 
Use Inquiry    : 1 
Global Bus Type: default (0) 
Check supported media : Disabled (0) 

11.6.2010 CD Image 10:43:02 AM #1 Text 0 File SCSIPTICommands.cpp, Line 450
LockMCN - completed sucessfully for IOCTL_STORAGE_MCN_CONTROL 
10:43:02 AM #2 Text 0 File Burncd.cpp, Line 3186
HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-H12N Buffer underrun protection activated
10:43:02 AM #3 Text 0 File Burncd.cpp, Line 3500 
Turn on Disc-At-Once, using CD-R/RW media
10:43:02 AM #4 Text 0 File DlgWaitCD.cpp, Line 307 
Last possible write address on media:   359848 ( 79:59.73) 
Last address to be written:             318783 ( 70:52.33)
10:43:02 AM #5 Text 0 File DlgWaitCD.cpp, Line 319 
Write in overburning mode: NO (enabled: CD)
10:43:02 AM #6 Text 0 File DlgWaitCD.cpp, Line 2988 
Recorder:  HL-DT-ST  DVDRAM G SA-H12N;    
CDR co de: 00 97  27 18; O SJ entry from: Pla smon Data  systems Ltd.    
ATIP Data:      Special    
Info [hex] 1: D0 00 A0, 2: 61 1B 12 (LI 97:27.18), 3: 4F 3B 4A ( LO 79:59.74)
Additional Info [hex] 1: 00 00 00 (invalid), 2: 00 00 00 (invalid), 
    3: 00 0 0 00 (invalid)
10:43:02 AM #7 Text 0 File DlgWaitCD.cpp, Line 493 
>>> Protocol of DlgWaitCD activities: <<< 
=========================================
10:43:02 AM #8 Text 0 File ThreadedTransferInterface.cpp, Line 785 
Nero Report 1

Nero Burning ROM Setup items (after recorder preparation)
 0: TRM_DATA_MODE1 (2 - CD-ROM Mode 1, Joliet)     
2 indices, index0 (150) not provided     
original disc pos #0 + 318784 (318784) = #318784/70:50.34     
not relocatable, disc pos for caching/writing not required/not required ->
  TRM_DATA_MODE1, 2048, config 0, wanted index0 0 blocks, length 318784 
  blocks [G: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-H12N] 

--------------------------------------------------------------
10:43:02 AM #9 Text 0 File ThreadedTransferInterface.cpp, Line 986 
Prepare [G: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-H12N] for write in CUE-sheet-DAO 
DAO infos: 
==========  
MCN: ""  
TOCType:  0x00; 
Se ssion Clo sed, disc  fixated  
Tracks 1 to 1:                                  Idx 0         Idx 1      
Next T rk    1: TRM_DATA_MODE1, 2048/0x00, FilePos             0        307200     6531768 32, ISRC "" 
DAO layout: 
===========
___Start_|____Track_|_Idx_|_CtrlAdr_|_____Size_|______NWA_|_RecDep__________ 
   -150  |  lead-in |   0 |    0x41 |        0 |        0 | 0x00 
    -150 |        1 |   0 |    0x41 |        0 |        0 | 0x00         
       0 |        1 |   1 |    0x41 |   318784 |   318784 | 0x00    
  318784 | lead-out |   1 |    0x41 |        0 |        0 | 0x00
10:43:02 AM #10 Text 0 File SCSIPTICommands.cpp, Line 240 
SPTILockVolume - completed successfully for FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME
10:43:02 AM #11 Text 0 File Burncd.cpp, Line 4286 
Caching options: cache CDRom or Network-Yes, small files-Yes (<64KB)
10:43:02 AM #12 Phase 24 File dlgbrnst.cpp, Line 1767 
Caching of files started
10:43:02 AM #13 Text 0 File Burncd.cpp, Line 4405 
Cache writing successful.
10:43:02 AM #14 Phase 25 File dlgbrnst.cpp, Line 1767 
Caching of files completed
10:43:02 AM #15 Phase 36 File dlgbrnst.cpp, Line 1767 
Burn process started at 48x (7,200 KB/s)
10:43:02 AM #16 Text 0 File ThreadedTransferInterface.cpp, Line 2733 
Verifying disc position of item 0 (not relocatable, no disc pos, no patch infos,  orig at #0): write at #0
10:43:02 AM #17 Text 0 File MMC.cpp, Line 17806 
StartDAO : CD-Text - Off
10:43:02 AM #18 Text 0 File MMC.cpp, Line 22488 
Set BUFE: Buffer underrun protection -> ON 
10:43:03 AM #19 Text 0 File MMC.cpp, Line 18034 
CueData, Len=32 41 00 00 14 00 00 00 00 41 01 00 10 00 00 00 00 
    41 01 01 10 00 00 02 00 41 aa 01 14 00 46 34 22 
10:43:03 AM #20 Text 0 File ThreadedTransfer.cpp, Line 268 
Pipe memory size 83836800
10:43:16 AM #21 Text 0 File Cdrdrv.cpp, Line 1405 
10:43:16.806 - G: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-H12N : Queue again later
10:43:42 AM #22 SPTI -1502 File SCSIPassThrough.cpp, Line 181 
CdRom1: SCSIStatus(x02) WinError(0) NeroError(-1502) 
Sense Key:  0x04 (KEY_HARDWARE_ERROR)
Nero Report 2
Nero Burning ROM Sense Code: 0x08
Sense Qual: 0x03 CDB Data:   0x2A 00 00 00 4D 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 
Sense Area: 0x70 00 04 00 00 00 00 10 53 29 A1 80 08 03 
Buffer x0c7d9a40: Len x10000 0xDC 87 EB 41 6E AC 61 5A 07 B2 DB 78 B5 
    D4 D9 24 0x8D BC 51 38 46 56 0F EE 16 15 5C 5B E3 B0 10 16 0x14 B1 
    C3 6E 30 2B C4 78 15 AB D5 92 09 B7 81 23 
10:43:42 AM #23 CDR -1502 File Writer.cpp, Line 306 
DMA-driver error, CRC error G: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-H12N
10:43:55 AM #24 Phase 38 File dlgbrnst.cpp, Line 1767 
Burn process failed at 48x (7,200 KB/s)
10:43:55 AM #25 Text 0 File SCSIPTICommands.cpp, Line 287 
SPTIDismountVolume - completed successfully for FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME
10:44:01 AM #26 Text 0 File Cdrdrv.cpp, Line 11412 
DriveLocker: UnLockVolume completed
10:44:01 AM #27 Text 0 File SCSIPTICommands.cpp, Line 450 
UnLockMCN - completed sucessfully for IOCTL_STORAGE_MCN_CONTROL
Existing drivers: Registry Keys:
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon
Nero Report 3
```

Comment: srry 2 here that. do u have a question?

Comment: i need knw reason for the error i am getting so that i could correct it

Comment: dirty or broken drive is my first guess.

Comment: Can you post the [log from the log window](http://cynthia.ownit.nu/ImgBurn/guide_functions/log01.png) when you try to burn a disc?

Comment: Agreed with msw, I feel sorry for your loss. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have attempted using multiple disks my personal option would be that the drive is faulty, I/O errors mean that the computer had an error when trying to read or write data to disk. My suggestion would be to *try* and boot on to a live linux distro such as [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download) this is very easy to do once booted into the system i would then attempt to burn a disk if it fails this would indicate that the issue is cross-platform and must then be a hardware fault (replace the drive). Good Luck