# dvd drive I/O error?

Tags: dvd, compact-disc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CD/DVD burn error in ImgBurn and Nero](https://superuser.com/questions/150920/cd-dvd-burn-error-in-imgburn-and-nero)

i get dis error evry time i burn a cd/dvd thru my dvd drive...!!

```
Nero Burning ROM bobby 4C85-200E-4005-0004-0000-7660-0800-35X3-0000-407M-MX37-**** (*) Windows XP 6.1
IA32 WinAspi: -
NT-SPTI used Nero Version: 7.11.3. Internal Version: 7, 11, 3,  (Nero Express) Recorder:             Version: UL01 - HA 1 TA 1 - 7.11.3.0  Adapter driver:                           HA 1  Drive buffer  :      2048kB  Bus Type      :      default CD-ROM:               Version: 52PP - HA 1 TA 0 - 7.11.3.0  Adapter driver:                           HA 1
=== Scsi-Device-Map === === CDRom-Device-Map ===
ATAPI-CD ROM-DRIVE-52MAX   F:   CdRom0 HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-H12N   G:   CdRom1 =======================
AutoRun : 1 Excluded drive IDs: WriteBufferSize: 83886080 (0) Byte BUFE           : 0 Physical memory     : 958MB (981560kB) Free physical memory: 309MB (317024kB) Memory in use       : 67 % Uncached PFiles: 0x0 Use Inquiry    : 1 Global Bus Type: default (0) Check supported media : Disabled (0) 
11.6.2010 CD Image 10:43:02 AM #1 Text 0 File SCSIPTICommands.cpp, Line 450
LockMCN - completed sucessfully for IOCTL_STORAGE_MCN_CONTROL 10:43:02 AM #2 Text 0 File Burncd.cpp, Line 3186
HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-H12N Buffer underrun protection activated
10:43:02 AM #3 Text 0 File Burncd.cpp, Line 3500 Turn on Disc-At-Once, using CD-R/RW media
10:43:02 AM #4 Text 0 File DlgWaitCD.cpp, Line 307 Last possible write address on media:   359848 ( 79:59.73) Last address to be written:             318783 ( 70:52.33)
10:43:02 AM #5 Text 0 File DlgWaitCD.cpp, Line 319 Write in overburning mode: NO (enabled: CD)
10:43:02 AM #6 Text 0 File DlgWaitCD.cpp, Line 2988 Recorder:  HL-DT-ST  DVDRAM G SA-H12N;    CDR co de: 00 97  27 18; O SJ entry from: Pla smon Data  systems Ltd.    ATIP Data:      Special    Info [hex] 1: D0 00 A0, 2: 61 1B 12 (LI 97:27.18), 3: 4F 3B 4A ( LO 79:59.74)      Additional Info [hex] 1: 00 00 00 (invalid), 2: 00 00 00 (invalid), 3: 00 0 0 00 (invalid)
10:43:02 AM #7 Text 0 File DlgWaitCD.cpp, Line 493 >>> Protocol of DlgWaitCD activities:  TRM_DATA_MODE1, 2048, config 0, wanted index0 0 blocks, length 318784 blo cks [G: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-H12N] --------------------------------------------------------------
10:43:02 AM #9 Text 0 File ThreadedTransferInterface.cpp, Line 986 Prepare [G: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-H12N] for write in CUE-sheet-DAO DAO infos: ==========  MCN: ""  TOCType:  0x00; Se ssion Clo sed, disc  fixated  Tracks 1 to 1:                                  Idx 0         Idx 1      Next T rk    1: TRM_DATA_MODE1, 2048/0x00, FilePos             0        307200     6531768 32, ISRC "" DAO layout: ===========  ___Start_|____Track_|_Idx_|_CtrlAdr_|_____Size_|______NWA_|_RecDep__________      -150 |  lead-in |   0 |    0x41 |        0 |        0 | 0x00      -150 |        1 |   0 |    0x41 |        0 |        0 | 0x00         0 |        1 |   1 |    0x41 |   318784 |   318784 | 0x00    318784 | lead-out |   1 |    0x41 |        0 |        0 | 0x00
10:43:02 AM #10 Text 0 File SCSIPTICommands.cpp, Line 240 SPTILockVolume - completed successfully for FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME
10:43:02 AM #11 Text 0 File Burncd.cpp, Line 4286 Caching options: cache CDRom or Network-Yes, small files-Yes ( ON 
10:43:03 AM #19 Text 0 File MMC.cpp, Line 18034 CueData, Len=32 41 00 00 14 00 00 00 00 41 01 00 10 00 00 00 00 41 01 01 10 00 00 02 00 41 aa 01 14 00 46 34 22 
10:43:03 AM #20 Text 0 File ThreadedTransfer.cpp, Line 268 Pipe memory size 83836800
10:43:16 AM #21 Text 0 File Cdrdrv.cpp, Line 1405 10:43:16.806 - G: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-H12N : Queue again later
10:43:42 AM #22 SPTI -1502 File SCSIPassThrough.cpp, Line 181 CdRom1: SCSIStatus(x02) WinError(0) NeroError(-1502) Sense Key:  0x04 (KEY_HARDWARE_ERROR)
Nero Report 2
Nero Burning ROM Sense Code: 0x08
Sense Qual: 0x03 CDB Data:   0x2A 00 00 00 4D 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 Sense Area: 0x70 00 04 00 00 00 00 10 53 29 A1 80 08 03 Buffer x0c7d9a40: Len x10000 0xDC 87 EB 41 6E AC 61 5A 07 B2 DB 78 B5 D4 D9 24 0x8D BC 51 38 46 56 0F EE 16 15 5C 5B E3 B0 10 16 0x14 B1 C3 6E 30 2B C4 78 15 AB D5 92 09 B7 81 23 
10:43:42 AM #23 CDR -1502 File Writer.cpp, Line 306 DMA-driver error, CRC error G: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-H12N
10:43:55 AM #24 Phase 38 File dlgbrnst.cpp, Line 1767 Burn process failed at 48x (7,200 KB/s)
10:43:55 AM #25 Text 0 File SCSIPTICommands.cpp, Line 287 SPTIDismountVolume - completed successfully for FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME
10:44:01 AM #26 Text 0 File Cdrdrv.cpp, Line 11412 DriveLocker: UnLockVolume completed
10:44:01 AM #27 Text 0 File SCSIPTICommands.cpp, Line 450 UnLockMCN - completed sucessfully for IOCTL_STORAGE_MCN_CONTROL
Existing drivers: Registry Keys:
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon
Nero Report 3
```

Comment: is this the same problem you posted about [in your earlier question](http://superuser.com/questions/150920/imgburn-cd-dvd-burn-error)?  you need to edit your earlier question, not post a new one on the same topic.

Comment: Correct spelling would help assist in the respectability of this question

Comment: i've added the nero log into your earlier question.  closing this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bum drive. Invoke warranty replacement, or get a new one if it's out of warranty.